# Shell Code inside a jpg file

Tags: shell, cmd

I have seen that it may be possible to run shell code in a jpg file. Is this true?
I just want to start cmd through a jpg. 
Or are there any other extensions where this would be possible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to do what you asked, eventually all file types are just a set of binaries, if you know and control the format, you can basically do anything you want. It is a low level implementation and requires deep knowledge of the format, header and execution type.

For further reading I recommend you this article:

http://archive.cert.uni-stuttgart.de/bugtraq/2004/09/msg00316.html

Comment: Yeah i have seen that but it is from 2001. i think they patched it. Any other methods?